# Does SQL Server 2017 Express LocalDB support FILESTREAM?

Tags: sql-server, localdb, sql-server-2017

I found only information about the 2016 version ([here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-2016-express-localdb)):

> **Restrictions**
>   **LocalDB** cannot be a merge replication subscriber.
>   **LocalDB** does not support FILESTREAM.
>   **LocalDB** only allows local queues for Service Broker.

There seems to be no document about the 2017 version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No changes in SQL Server 2017 due to the way LocalDb is designed